# Where is the keypad in Jensen's apartment?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I must be missing something really obvious, but I can't find the keypad that opens the stash behind the TV in Jensen's apartment.  Where is it located?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you walk in the door on the left just after the entrance to the kitchen. Passcode can be found in an email on the PC.[image]

Comment: -1 ... Y no Freehand circles?

Comment: @Josefvz is that a joke I am oblivious to? >.>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/145844 and i did't really -1'ed you i actually +1'ed you, because your answer is correct :D